# Retrofit android

Tags: php, java, android, retrofit2

У меня есть два вопроса которые я не понял в этой библиотеке. первый вопрос. У меня есть ServerApi в котором я показываю куда отправлять гет запрос и получить должен строку.

```
public interface ServerApi {
    @GET("serv.php")
    Call<String> getData();
}
```

билдю так

```
    Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
            .setLenient()
            .create();

    Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(base_url)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
            .build();
```

потом как положено запускаю асинхронно

```
       api.getData().enqueue(new Callback<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<String> call, Response<String> response) {
                String str = response.body();
                Toast.makeText(context , str , Toast.LENGTH_LONG ).show();
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<String> call, Throwable t) {
                Toast.makeText(context , t.toString() , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });
```

сервер отдает строку "салам все окей". А я тута просто салам получаю. Тоесть только первое слова. Как получить полностью?

втарой вопрос это Пост запрос в Ретрофит. Пишем онатацию Пост Передаем параметром @Body requestBody при этом этот класс тела он как то умудряется перекодировать в json как я понял и отправить на сервер. Ну ладно оставим как он это делает секретом но как мне получить строку на сервере. Тоесть например при отправки на пхп сервер я обычно получаю в данные в Post['key']. Ведь я в ретрофит не указовал это key. Под каким key он отправляется на сервер? как мне его получить на пхп сервере?

Comment: Посмотрите вот это https://stackoverflow.com/a/28426194/5892568